# When using change event of jquery ui autocomplete, it is showing id after seleting item, which should be not displyed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I used **jquery ui for auto-completing text box value**.

I created **array and bind name and id to the source of auto-complete**. Initially i was having  problem that is if user not select from the list then it should take some action on this . 
Then i searched on the above problem then i come to know solution that using **change event of ui auto-complete**.
But now it causes one new problem that is- **when i'm selecting item from list, then it is showing id in the text box and when i'm loosing focus then only it is showing name** .
It should not display id to the user which i'm setting for hidden field.

How to avoid this ?

I used following code-

code from web page is -

```
<div class="editor-field">

          @if (Model.ReportsTo != null)
          {
               @Html.TextBox("ReportsTo_FullName", Model.ReportsTo.FullName)
          }
          else
          {
                @Html.TextBox("ReportsTo_FullName", String.Empty, new { @id = "ReportsTo_FullName" })
          }
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportsToId, "ReportsToId")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportsToId)

</div>
```

Code from script-

```
$(function () {
    $("#ReportsTo_FullName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employee/AutocompleteSuggestions",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                    {
                        term: request.term,
                        moduleName: "Employee"
                    },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FullName, value: item.Id }
                    }
                    ))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#ReportsTo_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item != null) {
                $("#ReportsTo_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#ReportsToId").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#ReportsTo_FullName").css("color", "red");
            }
        }
    });
});
```